# TinyMCE how to put a div tag in a link?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I did a lot of testing but I can not manage a big problem with tinyMCE 3.xx

Whenever I want to insert a `<div>` tag type from a link farm link editor and places the `<div>` as a result, here is the code:

Before :

```
<a href="img.png" data-fancybox-group="image-gallery">
  <img src="img.png" alt="" />
  <div class="image-overlay-zoom"></div>
</a>
```

After :

```
<a href="img.png" data-fancybox-group="image-gallery">
<img src="img.png" alt="" />
</a>
<div class="image-overlay-zoom"></div>


tinyMCE.init({valid_elements : '*[*]'});
```

How can I put a `<div>` tag in a link?

Thanks

It does not work even disabling the automatic cleaning :

```
tinyMCE.init({cleanup : false'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies here after reading the following article :

http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/overcoming-magentos-wysiwyg-part-2-customizing-tinymce-settings/